# Type error = 'type' object is not subscritable points: list[Point] = field(init=False)

Tags: python, class, types, typeerror

I'm trying to reproduce the implementation of a method I found on Github. But I'm having a type error.

```
class Instance:
    path: str = False
    size: int = 10
    dimension: int = 10
    points: list[Point] = field(init=False)
    origin: Point = Point(0, 0, 0)
    finish: Point = Point(0, 0, 0)
    nb_vehicules: int = 2
    max_distance: float = 100
    max_capacity: int = 100000
    poid_min: int = 2
    poid_max: int = 10
```

The error refers to the line `points: list[Point] = field(init=False)`.

`Point` is a class that was defined before:

```
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float
    poid: int
```

Comment: Python version? (py -V)

Comment: You are using a version of Python in which `list` and `typing.List` are not aliased (don't remember when that happened). Either update your Python version to the latest stable or use `List[Point]`

Answer (score 0):

Your Python version is outdated.

Please update your Python to version 3.9+, that's when built-in types started supporting generic subscription.

Otherwise, you can use the typing module like so:

```
from typing import List

...
points: List[Point] = field(init=False)
...
```